# Deployment pipeline as a component of an application

Tags: continuous-integration, deployment, aws, serverless

I am writing a serverless application using AWS SAM. I am wondering, would it be a good idea to include in my template a definition of a CodePipeline (and CodeBuild for that matter) for deploying that very application?

The idea would be that on the initial deployment of an app, a CloudFormation stack would be created, containing not only application resources but also the pipeline to build it and deploy it.

I don't see an immediate issue with this approach but I am wondering if I am not missing something? Would you think it is a good idea or would you rather create a separate SAM/CF template to build the deployment pipeline?